# Golang-templates > How to update the result web page as soon as the template file (html) is changed

Tags: html, go, go-templates

I'm learning Golang and having some trouble with the web (html) templates.
Whenever I change the template file, it does not reflect in showing the result in the browser. The result shows the same content that was being shown previously.

How can I make the changed template come alive and show up on the browser as soon as the file is changed?

Comment: The browser doesn't even know the template file exists. The only way to do this would be with some complex JavaScript trickery using polling or websockets and a dedicated endpoint on the server watching the files and telling the browser to refresh.

Comment: How to make the browser always load the file from the server? I'm purely using SSR without any javascript.
How are other languages getting over this? I've used PHP and this is not an issue there when SSR is used.
Only in case of SPAs where the javascript is loading the page, this issue comes in, which is resolved by using version number or something from the server, so that the browser takes the server page once the version number string is changed. 
Can something similar be done here?

Comment: Sure. You could just add `?v=123` or whatever to the URL and it should work fine. Or you could use proper [cache control headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching#heuristic_caching), which would be the "correct" approach and will scale with proxies/CDNs/etc.

Comment: ?v=123 looks an excellent solution for a short term. I read about cache control headers. But this is only required for development. We'll require max cache in Production.
I'll revert if this is effective.